# Async/Await (TypeScript) with expressjs or another alternative

Tags: node.js, express, typescript, ecmascript-6

I would like to use Expressjs but ideally through TypeScript. I was hoping to be able to replace the Express standard callbacks with something like async/await or promises using TypeScript but I can't seem to find any examples.

Is anyone using expressjs with something other than callbacks, maybe promises? From typescript would be ideal.

I did look at Koa but my experience is this Expressjs but just wanted to be able to write it a little better and considering I am using typescript (or am able to use typescript), I thought there would be an alternative.

I know it's possible to wrap things using the Q library but it just doesn't seem natural, or maybe I am doing it wrong?

Comment: I did see this, but its JS specific https://github.com/caolan/async rather than being typescript. I would think there would be something else.

Comment: [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) are now standard in JavaScript (as of ES6, published last year). However, Express doesn't currently make use of them, though [plans to in future releases](https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/2259). You can still make use of them among other code inside a route handler, invoking Express' functions at the end of the chain – `(req, res, next) => getUser().then(user => res.render('profile', user), next)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is anyone using expressjs with something other than callbacks, maybe promises

Not the official API of using expressjs. However there is now `koa` from the team that made express : http://koajs.com/ which offers this out of the box